# Make next post button link to random post

Tags: php, customization, navigation

The normal behavior of this code is move to next post in order by id. Need to change this ascendent order to go instead to a random post (published).

```
<div class="navigation">
        <?php if (!empty($prevID)) { ?>
        <div class="alignleft">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prevID); ?>"
                title="<?php echo get_the_title($prevID); ?>">Previous</a>
            </div>
            <?php }
            if (!empty($nextID)) { ?>
            <div class="alignright">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextID); ?>"
                    title="<?php echo get_the_title($nextID); ?>">Next</a>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted does nothing but display. The code you need to alter is whatever is creating `$prevID` and `$nextID`, but that might not be entirely relevant.

Basically, you just need to grab a random post.

```
$rl = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'fields' => 'ids'
  )
); ?>
<div class="alignleft">
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($rl->posts[0]); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($rl->posts[0]); ?>">Random</a>
</div><?php
```

I don't see the point of two random post links but the same technique will work.

Also, using random links in your navigation isn't really navigation. It doesn't help your users navigate. It just randomly tosses them around the site.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the plugin [Redirect URL to Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-url-to-post/) and then add "?redirect_to=random" to the URL in href:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/?redirect_to=random"
   title="Random post">Go to random post</a>
```

Just need to make sure that you disable caching for URLs with ?redirect_to=random.